# Disable Task Bar in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

Tags: gnome, 13.10, gnome-tweak-tool

How do I disable the task bar in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. I enabled it somehow using the Gnome Tweak Tool but now I can't find the button to toggle it again.

I'm talking about the one which appears at the bottom in this [screenshot](http://s17.postimg.org/96ihri1jz/Screenshot_from_2013_11_17_23_51_55.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
Go to `Applications` -> `Tweak Tool` (usually comes by default with Ubuntu Gnome).
Once the `Tweak Tool` opens, go to the `Shell Extensions` tab and turn off `Window List`.